# GCP IoT grant device access to other cloud services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot

I have some IoT Devices on Google Cloud. They have private/public key pairs for authentication with the IoT Device Registry. I would like them to be able to access other authenticated cloud services, like Cloud Storage. Is there a way to leverage the unique device identity that I use to connect to the IoT Device registry to access other services? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not how you're meaning it, no. The device ID in Cloud IoT Core and the authentication there doesn't relate to the rest of the Cloud services, it's only relevant to the SSL handshake between device and IoT Core.

To access other services, you need to use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts).